# Display Touch Screen Keyboard in Windows Tablet through Unity 3D

Tags: windows-8, unity-game-engine

I am creating a registration page in my game in Unity. Data related features are working fine, but I am not getting the keyboard to Pop Up automatically/programatically when TextField is clicked. 
Is touch screen keyboard support available in Unity for Windows 8 Tablet? I have searched a lot of forums but did not get the solution. All say that this feature is not provided for Windows yet.
I read a solution on Unity's Documentation for Android and IOS, but nothing is available for Windows.

I tried:

```
Keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("",TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default,false,false,true);
```

But this is not allowing me to create a build for Windows Store. Shows me an error:

Assets\Script\RegiPage.cs(15,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TouchScreenKeyboard' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot do the function you are looking for .

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/186697-No-Keyboard-on-Windows-8